# Jquery/HTML: Check if input type image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I have a div which consists of `<input type="image">` tags. I have a button which when clicked should validate if at least one image input is selected. I tried the following which doesn't work

```
$("#step_two_show").click(function() {
        var img_selected = $('input[type="image"]:selected').length;
        if (img_selected > 0) {
            $("#step_one").hide();
            $("#step_two").show();
        } else {
            $("#pentype_error").show();
        }
    });
```

One more problem is that when I click the "step_two_show" button, the input image which was selected becomes unselected (which I think is contributing to the problem)

Comment: [input type="image"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) submits a form.

Comment: Any other efficient way to add images as inputs? Should I wrap them up in a div and handle the validation using custom jQuery code?

Comment: Maybe a button would do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using input type as image, used img tags. Then using jQuery on click event handler, added a css class `selected`. During validaiton, checked if the `selected` exists

```
$(".pen-type").click(function() {
        image_selected = true;
        $(this).css('border', "solid 2px gold");
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.pen-type.selected').not(this).css('border', 'none');
        $('.pen-type.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

$("#step_two_show").click(function() {
        
        if ($('.pen-type.selected').length > 0) {
            $("#step_one").hide();
            $("#step_two").show();
        } else {
            $("#pentype_error").show();
        }
    });
```